# How to write a minimal WhitespaceTokenizer in Rasa 3,0

Tags: python, rasa, rasa-nlu

I'd need a minimal example on how to write a custom tokenizer in Rasa 3.0, even if based on a simple .split() - it's just for learning. Thanks!

Comment: using Google `rasa nlu examples` I found [Rasa NLU Examples](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-nlu-examples) and there are [tokenizers](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-nlu-examples/tree/main/rasa_nlu_examples/tokenizers)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The API changed in Rasa v3.0. There's a proper [guide](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/custom-graph-components) on how to make custom components though.

Having said that, the [WhitespaceTokenizer](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/components#whitespacetokenizer) should suffice your use-case here.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll try out the link!